# How would I go about displaying my SQL data horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: php, css, sql

I need my data to be displayed in horizontal rows of 6 before dropping and creating a new row of 6 and so on...
[My page right now. Red outlines to illustrate each individual row of data from phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofIW9.jpg)

I have tried to do this with just CSS, but it seems to not work by normal means because every new row of data displayed is automatically pushed down.

```
        <?php

        $records = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY title");
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
    ?>
        <td>
            <div class="grid-artists">
                <div class="column-artists">
                    <div class="poster">
            <?php
                    echo '<img class="round" src="'.$data["img"].' " width="150" height="150"/>';
            ?>
                    <br>
                    <br><td><?php echo $data['title']; ?></td><br>
                    <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

.poster {
    width: 150px;
    background:rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.5);
    margin: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.grid-artists {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: min-content;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column-artists {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: please share your expected output

Comment: SHow us what you did with the CSS and the result and then we can tell you what you how to do it

Comment: @BhargavChudasama I can't provide any visual representation, but if you look at the linked screengrab I want 2pac to be displayed to the right of 100 gecs, 50 Cent to then be displayed to the right of 2Pac and so on. When the row eventually reaches the right side of the black box the nect entry should be displayed underneath 100 gecs and continue working it's way to the right. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `<td>` inside a `<div>`? Invalid. Read up on "css flex" or "css grid", probably the easiest way

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added the relevant css to the post

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP or SQL?

Comment: @brombeer I have to admit I didn't expect for this to be the issue, but I read up on grids and decided to change the display from grid to inline-grid and it works now. Thanks alot!